# Previous Running Totals in SQL Server / T-SQL based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling with adding to a table with a running total in SQL Server and I was hoping to get your help.

I have a table that started out this way:

```
EPDate             Item               BuyItem
----------------------------------------------
20150101           Mouse              10
20150101           Keyboard           100
20150202           Mouse              20
20150202           Keyboard           200
```

I want to generate the following table:

```
EPDate             Item        RunningTotal           Previous Running Total 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
20150101           Mouse              10                        0
20150202           Mouse              30                        10
20150101           Keyboard           100                       0
20150202           Keyboard           300                       100
```

I need help with the Previous Running Total column as I was actually able to generate the RunningTotal column using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY EPDate) AS RunningTotal
FROM
    MySampleTable
ORDER BY 
    Item DESC
```

But, how do I create the Previous Running Total column given that I have two different categories (Mouse, Keyboard) across different dates?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43fe130bcea2b98ddb26cfcb1762dbe3)**

```
SELECT *,SUM(buyItem) OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY EPDate) AS RunningTotal,
lag(BuyItem) over(PARTITION BY Item order by EPDate) as [Previous Running Total]
FROM MySampleTable order by item
```

OUTPUT:

```
d           item      buyItem     RunningTotal  Previous Running Total
20150101    Keyboard   100         100              0
20150202    Keyboard   200         300             100
20150101    Mouse       10         10              0
20150202    Mouse       20         30              10
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for the input - all the answers made sense and although advised not to go with LAG, the solution from fa06 worked best. I really appreciate all the help you've all provided! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about you subtract the value from the running total and modify your original query as follows.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(BuyItem) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY EPDate) AS RunningTotal,
    SUM(BuyItem) OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY EPDate) - BuyItem AS Previous Running Total
FROM
    MySampleTable
ORDER BY 
    Item DESC
```

Comment: By far a better approach than running lag on the running total.  Cleaner, faster, and shows an awareness of what the calculations actually ***are***. Would it be wrong to create another account so I can up vote again? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 SELECT *, SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY EPDate) AS RunningTotal 
         , SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, ORDER BY EPDate) - BuyItem  AS PreviousRunningTotal 
 FROM MySampleTable
```

Comment: Why bother with the expense of LAG()?  It's just Running Total minus Current Value...

Comment: @MatBailie Never thought that :)